# Focus on a Control When Switching Tabs

Tags: c#, .net

What I want to do is set the focus to a specific control (specifically a `TextBox`) on a tab page when that tab page is selected.

I've tried to call `Focus` during the Selected event of the containing tab control, but that isn't working. After that I tried to call focus during the `VisibleChanged` event of the control itself (with a check so that I'm not focusing on an invisible control), but that isn't working either.

Searching this site, I've come across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680/winforms-c-set-focus-to-first-child-control-of-tab-page) but that isn't working either. Although after that, I did notice that calling the `Focus` of the control does make it the `ActiveControl`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did this and it seems to work:

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` for the `tabControl`.
Check if `tabControl1.SelectedIndex` == the one I want and 
call `textBox.Focus();`

I'm using VS 2008, BTW.

---

Something like this worked:

```
private void tabControl1_selectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
      textBox1.Focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you know why it doesn't work in the Selected event, but does in the SelectedIndex event?

Comment: A tabcontrol steals focus on SelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 1):

Try the TabPage.Enter something like

```
        private void tabPage1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage page = (TabPage)sender;
            switch (page.TabIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    textBox1.Text = "Page 1";
                    if (!textBox1.Focus())
                        textBox1.Focus();

                    break;
                case 1:
                    textBox2.Text = "Page 2";

                    if (!textBox2.Focus())
                        textBox2.Focus();

                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
```