# Why can't I reliably focus a control in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, setfocus

I have a form that consists of various controls on the left and the main body is a browser window that displays a HTML file created by the other controls.  After generating a file I am attempting to set the focus onto the browser window so the scroll wheel works.

On every **ODD** attempt this works, on the **EVEN** attempts it does not.

There are two code paths (both starting from a button click) that generate output, both come down to:

```
Browser.Focus();
Browser.DocumentText = RenderAsHTML();
```

The first button updates a listbox on the left also, the second does not.  The odd/even pattern is independent of which button was pressed.

What in the world is going on here?

In trying the response below and then throwing things at it I found something very interesting:

The system believes the window *IS* focused.  Browser.Focused returns true even when it's not accepting scroll wheel messages.

To make it even stranger one test I did involved throwing a messagebox in there showing some variables--and when that box was cleared going back to the screen the scroll wheel worked 100% of the time.  Removing *ONLY* the MessageBox.Show line returned it to the old behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680/winforms-c-sharp-set-focus-to-first-child-control-of-tab-page

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: @GertArnold:  That's also talking about how to focus something but the answer there produces the same problem so it's not the answer to my mystery.

Answer (score 0):

on [Winforms c# - Set focus to first child control of TabPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680/winforms-c-sharp-set-focus-to-first-child-control-of-tab-page) will find a similar question, there the best answer says that you have to put

```
 ActiveControl = yourControlThatReceiveFocus;
```

Comment: This produces exactly the same result--the control gets focus every *OTHER* time.